# EF. How to use Include on property of interface type

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a trouble with using EF and don't know how to handle it correctly. 
I have 2 database tables: WebResource and UserGroup. I made interfaces for them:

```
public interface IUserGroup
{
    int Id { get; set; }

    string Name { get; set; }

    string DisplayName { get; set; }
}

public interface IWebResource
{
    int Id { get; set; }

    int Group_Id { get; set; }

    IUserGroup Group { get; set; }
}
```

also i've made an interface IUsersRepository which gives me access to my DB objects.

```
public interface IUsersRepository
{
    List<IUserGroup> UserGroups { get; set; }
    List<IWebResource> Controllers { get; set; }

    //TODO a little bit incorrect method
    List<IWebResource> GetUserResources(string username);

    List<IWebResource> GetResourcesByRole(string roleName);

    List<IWebResource> GetResourcesByController(string controllerName);
}
```

Then i made 2 implementations: Ado.Net implementation, which is of no interest in this question and EF implementation, wwhich looks like this:

```
public class UserGroup:IUserGroup
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}

public class WebResource:IWebResource
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int Group_Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Group_Id")]
    public IUserGroup Group { get; set; }

}
```

And in my Users Repository i have a method:

```
public List<IWebResource> GetResourcesByController(string controllerName)
    {
        var items = this.Controllers.Include("Group")
            .Where(c => c.ResourcePath == controllerName).ToList();
        var controllerGroups = new List<IWebResource>(items);
        return controllerGroups;
    }
```

This doesn't work. I get an Exceptions "Cannot find navigation property Group in WebResource". I then tried this:

```
public class WebResource:IWebResource
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int Group_Id { get; set; }

    public IUserGroup Group
    {
        get { return EfGroup; }
        set { EfGroup = new UserGroup(); }
    }

    [ForeignKey("Group_Id")]
    public UserGroup EfGroup { get; set; }
```

}

And change Include("Group") to Include("EfGroup"). Now it works cool, but is very-very ugly and i totally don't like it. How can i implement this correctly?

Comment: You can't use `Include` on your Repository. Since your repository does not expose `IQueryable`.

Comment: @Aron My Repository is DbContext. I need something more?
Here is it's signature <code>public class EfUsersRepository : DbContext,IUsersRepository </code>

Comment: Your `IUsersRepository` MUST expose its properties as `IQueryable<T>`.

Comment: So i can't return eager-loaded entity set?

Comment: The concept of "Eager loading" and "Querying" only exists in `IQueryable`, your DbContext/Repository MUST expose `IQueryable` for ANY Entity Framework features to work. **YOU MUST EXPOSE YOUR PROPERTIES AS `IQueryable<T>`**. Further more, you CANNOT create methods like `GetUserResources(string username)`, due to how Entity Framework compiles Expressions to SQL.

Comment: `EfGroup` is a navigation property, `Group` isn't. `Include("EfGroup")` will work, `Include("Group")` won't.

Comment: Just a little question. How do another implementations of `IUserGroup` and `IWebResource` look like? I can't imagine any difference. Why do you ever have invented these interfaces?

Comment: @Dennis, another implementation doesn't have any attributes and is filled with data from SqlDataReader. That's why i made such an interface.

Comment: @Aron OK, i can use IQueryable<T>, but i still don't understand how to write implementation of my Data types in EF. I need to use IQueryable<IUserGroup> instead IUserGroup for Group property? And how do people write mockable systems for EF then?

Comment: @AlexVoskresenskiy "how do people write mockable systems for EF" what is the question? What do you want to mock? By the way, there is no reason to use interfaces for you POCOs, they should be property bags.